# How play web audio with bluetooth devices

Tags: android, html, browser, bluetooth, web-audio-api

I programmmed a website which uses text to speech engine to generate audio files.

Then these mp3 files are started using Web Audio API.

Everything works fine when hearing aufio from speakers on a computer or on a smart phone.

However, as soon as I connect my bluetooth helmet to the smart phone, the audio is not played.

Is it a famous issue that Web Audio API doesn't work with bluetooth devices, or does the issue come from my code?

Do I need to change the context's destination ? How can I set it to buetooth? (ex : https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/)

```
source.connect(context.destination); // connect the source to the context's destination (the speakers)
```

This question has already been posted on stackoverflow, but I can't find an answer.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi use the web bluetooth library for more reference read this [here](https://urish.medium.com/start-building-with-web-bluetooth-and-progressive-web-apps-6534835959a6)

Comment: FYI, web-bluetooth doesn't actually (yet) do anything with audio. It's only intended for use with BLE/GATT, as opposed Bluetooth Classic Audio profiles like A2DP, HFP, or the Bluetooth Classic Audio encoders like SBC or mSBC. Audio over BLE will be common someday soon, but not yet.